# How to implement a group of elements in the drop-down list ObjectSelect

Tags: php, select, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, zend-form

How to implement a group of elements in the drop-down list [ObjectSelect](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/form-element.md#example-6-implementing--support) 'optgroup_identifier'

`Form\CategoryForm.php`

```
$this->add([
    'type'  => ObjectSelect::class,
     'name' => 'category',
    'options' => [
        'label' => 'Категория',
        'object_manager' => $this->getObjectManager(),
        'target_class'   => Category::class,
        'property'       => 'name',
        'optgroup_identifier' => '???',
        'optgroup_default'    => 'Главная',
        'empty_option'   => '== Категория ==',
        'is_method'      => true,
        'find_method'    => [
            'name'   => 'findAllChildCategories',
            'params' => [
            ],
        ],
    ],
]);
```

Category Table is relevant [Self-referencing](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-self-referencing)

`Entity\Category.php`

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Application\Entity\Category", mappedBy="parent", cascade={"remove"})
 */
private $children;

/**
 * @var \Application\Entity\Category
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\Category", inversedBy="children")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 * })
 */
private $parent;
```

Group name must be the parent category
`$category->getParent()->getName()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankfully for this case, `Doctrine` does not do any queries to get groupings; it does it internally. `optgroup_identifier` is just name of a getter it uses to get group names, therefore that getter can return anything you want.

In `Entity\Category`, add a method dedicated to returning parent name of a category. Ensure it does not coincide with any fields so `Doctrine` does not return a whole object proxy into a form. For example:

```
public function getParentName() {
    if(!$this->parent) return '';
    return $this->parent->getName();
}
```

Since root categories will not have a parent, `$this->parent` will be `null`. Look out for that case to avoid script crashing and return empty string as a designation for it.

Then, put this getter name in `optgroup_identifier` of the form. Final result will be as in screenshot with sample data.[image]